# Changing CRS in QGIS due to pop up window: "CRS warning! Warning: Input layers have non-matching CRS. This may cause unexpected results.”

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm using GIS to map the movement of animals and their speed and density in different habitat types using shape polygons.

When I got to the step ;Count points in polygon' a pop up window appeared saying:"CRS warning! Warning: Input layers have non-matching CRS. This may cause unexpected results.”
I clicked ‘ok' however this meant that the attributes table that I then opened had no GPS speed values.

I'd like to know how to convert the CRS for this habitat shape polygon from 'Selected CRS (EPSG: 4326, WGS 84)' to 'Selected CRS (EPSG: 7405, OSGB 1936 / British National Grid)'.

Answer (score 3):

Choose tab **processing** > **toolbox**

After that, choose **QGIS geoalgorithms** > **vector general tools** > **reproject layer**

Then pick the one you want.

Comment: Rightclick on the layer and `Save As ...` to a different name and CRS does the same in an easier way.